# Return activerecord record property as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I wanted to get Users' name I'd do something like this

```
User.select(:name).find(55)
```

This would return :

```
#<User name: "Peter">
```

How do I get just `"Peter"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.name`, like so

```
user = User.select(:name).find(55)
user.name
```

Or

```
User.select(:name).find(55).name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the names and you want to avoid object instanciation

```
User.where(id: 55).pluck(:name).first
```

And you will totally avoid the cost of instanciating an activeRecord object